# Removing shadows from UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ios5

I use a web view to display small pdf files. In the interest of aesthetics, I'd like to remove the grey border around the PDF. Is there any way around it? I've looked at various resources none of which seem to work or the solution no longer works in iOS5.

Also, is there any way of stopping the scroll if there's only one page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shadows are actually UIImageView subviews of the UIScrollView (or the equivalent in iOS5 UIWebView).

So in iOS4:

```
for (UIView* subView in [webView subviews])
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        for (UIView* shadowView in [subView subviews])
        {
            if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [shadowView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in iOS5 and above:

```
for (UIView* shadowView in [webView.scrollView subviews])
{
    if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [shadowView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Colas I don't think webviews have shadows under iOS7.

Comment: I am talking about the shadow around the webview, like a grey frame.

Answer (score 3):

Works great with iOS 9

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    for (UIView *object in webView.scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([object class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
            UIView *pdfView = object;
            for (UIView *pdfObjectSubview in pdfView.subviews) {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([pdfObjectSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIPDFPageView"]) {
                    UIView *uiPDFPageView = pdfObjectSubview;
                    uiPDFPageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great on iOS 8 too.

Comment: I have this 4-page pdf. The shadow are still in last 2 pages? Any idea why?

Comment: @Rhenz, in macOS you can only get 'visiblePages' from the PDFDocument class. I suspect not all page views are loaded at the point you are setting the shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the border and shadow:

```
[[yourView layer] setBorderColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[[yourView layer] setBorderWidth: 0.0f];
[[yourView layer] setShadowColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[[yourView layer] setShadowOpacity: 0.0f];
[[yourView layer] setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. I am using navigation Controller
I hope it will help

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

One more way is there, Just go to storyboard and select Controller where the web view is present. And go to attribute inspector and uncheck the

> adjust scroll view insects