# Seamless UIWebview background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Is there a way to get rid of the borders of UIWebView? Right now even if I set the background to white, I see a border when scrolling outside of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480571/removing-shadows-from-uiwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove the grey areas, You can disable scroll thats seem be best way.

We currently have transparent background set on UIWebView

```
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In the HTML

```
<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0style="background-color:transparent">
```