# UIWebView display PDF and hide gray shadow in iOS7

Tags: pdf, ios7, uiscrollview, shadow

I'm trying to remove/hide the shadow from an UIWebView that displays a PDF in iOS7.
I've tried **all** solutions on stackoverflow and also others from the Internet, but it doesn't work.
Maybe it's because I'm using NSURLSession to load a PDF from a server and then display it.

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

My first guess was that it doesn't work because the NSURLSession delegates are not on the main thread but even if I remove the subviews (that contain the shadow) on the main thread and call `setNeedsDisplay` it doesn't change.

I'm starting a `DownloadTask` and when the task is finished and the delegate gets called I remove the layers.

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
    [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];


    // remove shadow layers from scrollview
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

        for (UIView* subView in [self.webView subviews])
        {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                for (UIView* shadowView in [subView subviews])
                {
                    if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                        [shadowView setHidden:YES];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [self.webView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
```

Even if a remove the GCD async block and it's executed in the same thread it doesn't change anything. I've also tried to call it in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`.

Any tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: I think the same answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480571/removing-shadows-from-uiwebview/33152456#33152456

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 for (UIView *object in webView.scrollView.subviews) {
      if ([NSStringFromClass([object class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
           UIView *pdfView = object;
           for (UIView *pdfObjectSubview in pdfView.subviews) {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([pdfObjectSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIPDFPageView"]) {
                     UIView *uiPDFPageView = pdfObjectSubview;
                     uiPDFPageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

}